# Python threading deadlock

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock

I have two threads (producer and consumer) and I share the data with `Queue`. The problem is, that when I forcefully abort the producer, the consumer sometimes locks.

I read in the docs that canceling a thread with queue might corrupt the queue and cause deadlock. I don't acquire any locks explicitly but reading the source of Queue.py says that `put` and `get` are doing so.

Please, does anyone know of it might be the case that when I abort the thread, it might be in the middle of `get`/`put`, i.e. using the lock and then not releasing it? What can I do about it? I sometimes need to terminate the producer prematurely. Would using processes, instead of threads, make any difference?

Comment: How do you abort the thread? Ctrl+C?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: can you post some code so we can know what's going on?

Comment: You can't postpone the thread abortion until after the thread releases it's lock on a the queue?

Comment: @JoelCornett: unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your deadlock is due to not finished threads. If you have linux you can use injector from [pyrasite](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrasite) to print backtrace (you would know where you program hung)

If you are using any locks in your signal handler - then probably this is your deadlock
(that's a bit complicated, please ask if you want explanation for that)

Creating processes instead of threads surely change situation but remember that any data exchange and synchronization is much complicated.

Comment: How do I "finish" a thread? I thought that when run() reaches the end it's finished. And I don't use any signal handler myself, maybe Queue.py does? http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py

Comment: Yes, if run() reach end then it's finished (for elegance main thread should do "join()" on it) -> you can add debug information to be sure that your thread (producer/consument) ended because it may be hung on queue.get() or even queue.put() (!)

Comment: I think this "hanging" is exactly what's happening. The question is, I do abort one thread so it wont reach the end - what am I supposed to do? I mean, I need to abort it but then the queue seems to hang..?

Comment: If you abort producer then consumer that is waiting on queue.get() must be awaken, so you can not just abort one thread.

Comment: I've sent "MyQueue" class that is a bit simpler and got "abort" function - you can verify. If you still need more help then please say something more at least about system (linux/windows/mac) and python version, then I will suggest how to find the location of deadlock.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11763/discussion-between-ddzialak-and-ecir-hana)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
import threading

class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []
        self.tlock = threading.Semaphore(0)
        self.dlock = threading.Lock()
        self.aborted = False

    def put(self, arg):
        try:
            self.dlock.acquire()
            self.tasks.append(arg)
        finally:
            self.dlock.release()
            self.tlock.release()

    def get(self):
        if self.aborted:
            return None
        self.tlock.acquire()
        if self.aborted:
            self.tlock.release()
            return None
        try:
            self.dlock.acquire()
            if self.tasks:
                return self.tasks.pop()
            else: # executed abort
                return None
        finally:
            self.dlock.release()

    def abort(self):
        self.aborted = True
        self.tlock.release()

# TESTING

mq = MyQueue()
import sys

def tlog(line):
    sys.stdout.write("[ %s ] %s\n" % (threading.currentThread().name, line))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def reader():
    arg = 1
    while arg is not None:
        tlog("start reading")
        arg = mq.get()
        tlog("read: %s" % arg)
    tlog("END")

import time, random
def writer():
    try:
        pos = 1
        while not mq.aborted:
            x = random.random() * 5
            tlog("writer sleep (%s)" % x)
            pending = x
            while pending > 0:
                tosleep = min(0.5, pending)
                if mq.aborted:
                    return
                time.sleep(tosleep)
                pending -= tosleep

            tlog("write: %s" % x)
            mq.put("POS %s  val=%s" % (pos, x))
            pos += 1
    finally:
        tlog("writer END")

def testStart():
    try:
        for i in xrange(9):
            th = threading.Thread(None, reader, "reader %s" % i, (), {}, None)
            th.start()
        for i in xrange(3):
            th = threading.Thread(None, writer, "writer %s" % i, (), {}, None)
            th.start()
        time.sleep(30) # seconds for testing
    finally:
        print "main thread: abort()"
        mq.abort()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testStart()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to abort the thread as above because a task might take too long to finish.